# sharepoint is slow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, share

My SharePoint is slow from few days, I did shrinking SharePoint_config log file. What else can I do? Can I stop any service form these lists?

- Access Database Service 2010
- Access Services
- App Management Service
- Business Data Connectivity Service
- Central Administration
- Claims to Windows Token Service
- Distributed Cache
- Excel Calculation Services
- Machine Translation Service
- Managed Metadata Web Service
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application
- Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow
- Search Host Controller Service
- Search Query and Site Settings Service
- Secure Store Service
- SharePoint Server Search
- SQL Server PowerPivot System Service
- User Profile Service
- Visio Graphics Service
- Word Automation Services
- Work Management Service

My site I am using lists and workflows only and what else to improve performance of the site

Comment: Poor SharePoint performance is normally a symptom of an insufficiently specced SQL Server, or poorly configured SQL Server. Turning off services rarely helps, and only does help if memory usage is stressed on the WFE/App servers.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using it you can stop the following like Kalpesh said:

> 1.App Management Service - If you are not using SharePoint 2013 App in your environment
>
> 2.Business Data Connectivity Service - If you are not using any external list or external data column.
>
> 6.Word Automation Service - This service is used for conversion of the document e.g. Converting word file to PDF. So in your server if you are not using anywhere, may be any in custom code(in customization) then you can stop this service as well.

And also

•Excel Calculation Services

•Visio Graphics Service

•SQL Server PowerPivot System Service

Here are some useful links to check for performance optimization:

[Improving SharePoint Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.08.insidesharepoint.aspx)

[What I did to improve my SharePoint Performance by Benjamin Niaulin](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/improving-sharepoint-performance)

[SharePoint Performance Optimization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc964305.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

"SharePoint is slow" is a very broad statement. Your slowness might not have a thing to do with the service applications you have activated.

One thing to consider is caching. Are you making use of [Output Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa661294(v=office.14).aspx)? If not, it might be worth investigating. If you are using SP2013, and are making a lot of use of personalization features, [Distributed Cache](http://blogs.technet.com/b/uktechnet/archive/2013/05/07/guest-post-distributed-cache-service-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) might also be a potential means of getting a faster user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop following service application if you are not using it

1. App Management Service - If you are not using SharePoint 2013 App in your environment
2. Business Data Connectivity Service - If you are not using any external list or external data column.
3. Managed Metadata Web Service - If you are not using any Managed Metadata column, Managed navigation, Enterprise keyword in your farm
4. Search Host Controller Service - This is the service which should use more resource from server. So if you don't want search functionality then you can stop it as well.
5. Secure Store Service Application - If you are not using anywhere like in BDC or in InfoPath data connection files.
6. Word Automation Service - This service is used for conversion of the document e.g. Converting word file to PDF. So in your server if you are not using anywhere, may be any in custom code(in customization) then you can stop this service as well.

Hope you will get this helpful.